# What's the correct way of loading AWS credentials from role in a Fargate task using AWS SDK Go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-sdk-go

I have the following snippet:

```
awsCredentials := credentials.NewChainCredentials(
    []credentials.Provider{
        &ec2rolecreds.EC2RoleProvider{
            Client: ec2metadata.New(newSession, aws.NewConfig()),
        },
        &credentials.SharedCredentialsProvider{},
        &credentials.EnvProvider{},
    })
```

which works fine whenever the code is running on an EC2 instance or when the access/secret key are passed through variables (used for local testing).

However, this code is failing when running on ECS+Fargate because `NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain`. Checked the environment variables of the running container and it has the expected `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`, so the `credentials.EnvProvider` should read it.

So, my question is, what's the correct way of reading these credentials? Because the problem I'm facing is not about lack of permissions (which would indicate an error in the policy / role), but that code is not able to get the credentials.

**UPDATE**

I have narrowed this to the use of `ec2rolescreds`.

Using this simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials/ec2rolecreds"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/ec2metadata"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    newSession, err := session.NewSession()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    awsCredentials := credentials.NewChainCredentials(
        []credentials.Provider{
            &ec2rolecreds.EC2RoleProvider{
                Client: ec2metadata.New(newSession, aws.NewConfig()),
            },
            &credentials.SharedCredentialsProvider{},
            &credentials.EnvProvider{},
        })

    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("us-east-1"),
        Credentials: awsCredentials},
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Create S3 service client
    svc := s3.New(sess)

    result, err := svc.ListBuckets(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Buckets:")

    for _, b := range result.Buckets {
        fmt.Printf("* %s created on %s\n",
            aws.StringValue(b.Name), aws.TimeValue(b.CreationDate))
    }
}
```

If I remove `ec2rolescreds`, everything works fine both local and in ECS+Fargate.

However, if I run this code as is, I get the same error of `NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, a session can be configured using a Config object.

Reading through the specs of this object, it says for Credentials:

```
// The credentials object to use when signing requests. Defaults to a
// chain of credential providers to search for credentials in environment
// variables, shared credential file, and EC2 Instance Roles.
Credentials *credentials.Credentials
```

The defaults are already what my snippet was doing, so I removed all the `awsCredentials` block and now it's working fine everywhere. Locally, EC2, Fargate...

**UPDATE**

To expand the answer, the reason why removing the `awsCredentials` made this work is because, if you check the SDK's code, https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/aws/defaults/defaults.go#L107, the default credentials check both `EnvProvider` and `RemoteCredProvider`.

By overriding the default chain credentials, it was not able to look for credentials in `RemoteCredProvider`, which is the provider that handles the environment variable `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_FULL_URI`.

Comment: hello, what was the final code? It is not clear from your answer what was the final solution. Thanks

Comment: I added the final code as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67307043/3732742) @Madeo.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to initialize clients using sessions instead of credentials, i.e:

```golang
conf := aws.NewConfig().WithRegion("us-east-1")
sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(conf))

svc := s3.New(sess)
// others:
//   svc := sqs.New(sess)
//   svc := dynamodb.New(sess)
//   ...
```

Because, as @Ay0 points, the default credential chain already includes both **`EnvProvider`** and **`RemoteCredProvider`**.

**In case you still need the credentials, you can use:**

```golang
creds := stscreds.NewCredentials(sess, "myRoleARN")
```

as the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go#hdr-Configuring_Credentials) points out. Notice that the policy of the role must have the `sts:AssumeRole` action enabled. For more information, here are the [`stscreds.NewCredentials(...)` docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials/stscreds#NewCredentials)